# Parameter value in Razor named page handler is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I'm using Razor Pages in an ASP.NET MVC web application (.NET 7).
In a Razor page, I added a named page handler next to the default OnGetAsync handler.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetGetStatesAsync(string country)
{
    ...
}
```

This method is called from a JavaScript function.

```js
$('.js-select-country').change(function (e) {
    
    var url = "MyPage?handler=getStates&country=US";
    
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        ...
    });
```

The page handler is being called but the country parameter is null.
I've played around with escaping the ampersand in the query string like & and %26 but that's also didn't fix it for me. Either the parameter is still null or the default OnGetAsync method is being called (with %26 in the url).
It's also tried a route rather than a query string (getStates/US) and marking the C# parameter with FromRoute, but then also the wrong method is being called.

What should I change so that the parameter value is correctly set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure that the url should be written like the following code:

```
var url = '?handler=GetStates&country=US',
```

But I have to admit it is confusing that the first querystring parameter starts with `&` instead of `?` which it is normally. I have also seen where a forward slash is used in the beginning like:

```
'/?handler=GetStates&country=US'
```

Perhaps then the handler is the first querystring parameter..

Another Razor Page handler way I have seen:

```
url: "@Url.Page("/MyPage")?handler=GetStates&country=US",
```

Comment: Your last suggestion with @Url.Page worked for me.
"@Url.Page("/MyPage")?handler=GetStates&country=US"

Then the country parameter in my C# handler method is assigned.
Thanks!